# c++ expected unqualified-id (class inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an application that has subclasses of User.

At the moment, I'm trying to pass an int which will be used to identify the user login number, however, I'm having problems declaring my subclass constructor.

User.h

```
class User 
{
    public:
        User(int);
    private:
        int loginNumber;
};
```

User.cpp

```
User::User(int theLoginNUmber)
:LoginNumber(theLoginNumber) { }
```

AdminUser.h

```
class AdminUser : public User
public:
    AdminUser(int);
private:
    int loginNumber;
};
```

AdminUser.cpp

```
AdminUser::User(int theLoginNumber) // requires unqualified-id
:loginNumber(theLoginNumber) {}
```

Comment: Change `AdminUser::User(int theLoginNumber) ` to `AdminUser::AdminUser(int theLoginNumber)`

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got definition of Admin user constructor wrong, here is the correct one:

```
AdminUser::AdminUser(int theLoginNumber)
        : User(theLoginNumber) { }
```

Since User doesn't have default constructor, you have to call the parametric one from initialization section.

However loginNumber can be protected in User class:

```
class User {
public:
    User(int);
protected:
    int loginNumber;
};
```

Now you inherit loginNumber as protected so you don't need it in AdminUser:

```
class AdminUser : public User
public:
    AdminUser(int);
};
```

**Note:** it contains loginNumber with correct value(set by constructor).

As @Mossi92 noted, you can go a bit further and implement a getter into User class, which will be inherited too:

```
class User {
    public:
        User(int);
    protected:
        int loginNumber;

        int login() const noexcept {
            return loginNumber;
        }
    };
```

However in this case you should think which class access modifier is the best this function. I'd say login number should be something invisible to outer world so I chose protected. This function now can be called only from inherited or friend classes.

Lets add simple print which calls inherited function in constructor:

```
AdminUser::AdminUser(int theLoginNumber)
        : User(theLoginNumber) {
    std::cout << login() << "\n";
}
```

And if we run:

```
int main() {
    AdminUser admin(1234);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1234
```

Comment: @Mossi92 glad I could help buddy.

Comment: For anyone else reading, you can go 1 step further from Marzi's answer by adding a function User::getLoginNumber() { std::cout << loginNumber; return loginNumber; } this will inherit down and you can call the function by calling admin.getLoginNumber... this will work for other user classes i.e. StudentUser student(2345); student.getLoginNumber()

Comment: you are right, but a little better one would to have that getter const qualified

Comment: One more question, when inheriting from a base class, should all the subclasses be listed in the base class definition? Wherever a user is defined, it is almost guaranteed it will be a type of user.